# How to correctly display date time fetched from Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> theSection = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    //return [[[theSection name]componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"]objectAtIndex:0];

    return [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[theSection name]] dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
}
```

I want to use `NSDateFormatter` to display date time fetched from core data and display as required.

**UPDATE 1**

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[f setDateFormat:@"dd:mm:yy hh:mm"];
NSDate *d = [f dateFromString:[theSection name]];

return [f stringFromDate:d];
```

This also not working :(

**UPDATE 2**

```
NSLog(@"TEST=>%@",[theSection name]);
```

displaying `2013-05-09 11:58:28 +0000` but in database its store like this

```
389773826.504289
```

Comment: maybe you should tell how is the required format for the date. If not, its hard to know

Comment: @pdrcabrod mm:dd:yy hh:mm:ss

Comment: What happened when you used : `[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[theSection name]] dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];` ?

Comment: @pdrcabrod getting (null) in NSLog and empty header in table, please also view update in my question but same problem. The code in comment show the date time but its not in required format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[f setDateFormat:@"MM:dd:yy hh:mm"];

// The current section:
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.controller sections] objectAtIndex:section];
// One arbitrary object in this section:
NSManagedObject *obj = [[sectionInfo objects] objectAtIndex:0];
// The date value of this object (and all objects of this section):
NSDate *date = [obj valueForKey:@"date"]; // <-- use your "sectionNameKeyPath" here

return [f stringFromDate:date];
```

Reason: You use a date attribute for sectioning the table view. `[sectionInfo name]`
converts the date to a string, which makes it difficult to convert the
date to a different format. This approach accesses the date value directly,
and converts it to the desired format.

Comment: @S.J. Martin's approach is correct. This with my one (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070597/doubts-on-concurrency-with-objects-that-can-be-used-multiple-times-like-formatte) allows you to boost performance ;). Formatter are expensive to create. +1 as always, Martin

Comment: @MartinR Please also view this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482239/why-nspredicate-not-working

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not care about the format, dates are stored in the DB. This is private.
2. Assuming, that [section name] returns a string, you need a date formatter, that understands *that* format. (Looks like UTC.) Then you need a date formatter, which is set to the *output* format. Put the string in the first formatter, take out the date and then put the date in the second formatter.

Comment: You can see in my question I already did that but problem still exist.